# linux, владелец файла

Tags: linux

Доброго дня!
Ситуация:
Есть директория на сервере куда некое количество пользователей копирует файлы при через scp. Файл кладется на сервер имея в качестве владельца того кто данный файл копировал.
Вопрос:
Возможно ли как то указать пользователя, который будет ставиться владельцем каждого скопированного файла, не зависимо от того кто этот файл скопировал?

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется именно менять пользователя, то написать скриптец, который будет это делать.

Если требуется изменить права на файл которые выдаются по умолчанию, то umask.

Comment: Решение со скриптом очевидно. А umask обрабатывает только создание новых файлов, если не ошибаюсь. Есть ли средства ОС для обработки подобной задачи?

Comment: chown http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown

Comment: Наверняка таких средств нету и лучше делать скрипт. Тут дальше два типа развития событий :

 1. Дергать скрипт по крону. 
 2. Дергать скрипт по завершению копирования .

ЗЫ

Разве umask не распространяется на свеже скопированные файлы ?

Comment: @sonniy, под *unmask* Вы видимо имели ввиду **umask**?

Если файл уже есть, то копирование просто меняет его *содержимое*, не затрагивая владельца, группу и права (-rwxrwxrwx).

Comment: Судя из описания этого файла на сервере еще нет.